# few small div inside a big div flows down

Tags: html, scroll

i have created a div of width 615px and 100px height. and i have created about 10 div inside that div of 90 * 80px. now the problem is that when the area of main div ends these small divs inside the main div flows down. i dont want to flows down i want that they will display in a row. if they over flow i will hidden them with using overflow hidden or i will give them horizontal scroll bar.
 it looks something like this now

[image]

help please

Answer (score 0):

Add another div inside your main div and wrapping the 10 internal divs. Set the width of this wrapper div to the width needed to accomodate all 10 internal divs.